# Xcode immediate autocompletion (not only to the next CamelCase)

Tags: autocomplete, xcode

How to make the autocompletion feature return the current suggestion (from "completion list") **in full**?

That is, how **not** to jump only to the next CamelCase with <kbd>TAB</kbd> ... but instead have, say, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> choose the suggestion **immediately/in full**?

### Example

Having `CGPDFStringGetLength` selected in the "completion list", one would have to press <kbd>TAB</kbd> four (4) times!

1. first <kbd>TAB</kbd> get to `CGPDF`
2. then to `CGPDFString`
3. then to `CGPDFStringGet`
4. then to `CGPDFStringGetLength`

It would be nice to have <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> (for example) make the above a one-step process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's Enter. I'm not sure. Let me know if this worked.

This question is more stackoverflow-ish than superuser-ish.

*Later Edit:* This can be changed from Key Bindings settings. The symbol to look for is ↩ . To add another symbol for immediate autocompletion you need to add another shortcut for "Insert Newline" command.

Comment: Indeed it is Enter ... is it also possible to **change it** (it's not a bad shortcut, though)? I can't find it in "Key Bindings" preferences; there are only 3 shortcuts under "Code Completion".

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-keybindings_preferences/CustomizingKeyboardShortcuts/CustomizingKeyboardShortcuts.html

Comment: Yes, that's the built-in help. Nevertheless, how can I search for shortcuts with Enter in them? Pasting ⌅ in the search bar doesn't (seem to) work ...

Comment: I found the symbol for Return: ↩ . To add another symbol for immediate autocompletion you need to add another shortcut for "Insert Newline" command.

Comment: Radoo, that's great ... would never have thought of looking at the "Insert Newline". Thank you.